# simple question regarding isomorphisms relating to ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I have a simple question about isomorphisms and ideals. Let $\mathcal O_F$ be the ring of integers in some quadratic number field $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ and let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt d$ over $\mathbb Z$. Then  $\mathcal O_F \simeq \mathbb Z[x]/(f(x))$, which I understand.

What I don't get is this: according to this document (http://www.math.umass.edu/~weston/cn/notes.pdf, on page 54)   it follows $ \mathcal O_F/p \mathcal O_F \simeq\mathbb (\mathbb Z[x]/f(x))/p \simeq \mathbb Z[x]/(p,f(x)) \simeq \mathbb F_p[x]/(f(x))$.  How does this follow?

Comment: anyone have ideas?

Comment: Use $\mathbb{Z}/p\simeq \mathbb{F}_p$ to conclude $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p)\simeq \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, and then mod out $(f(x)$.

Comment: thanks dietrich, but I don't see how the rest follows from that. It also seems to me that the author has two meanings of $(p)$ :  $p\mathcal O_F$ and $p\mathbb Z$